# JIRA API Error: 'It is not on the appropriate screen, or unknown' when calling Create Issue endpoint

Tags: ruby, jira

I met an issue when I call the create issue API in my code, the error is `It is not on the appropriate screen`, or unknown.' But when trying the test API with the same parameters in postman, it succeeds, is there anyone who knows the reason for this error?

This is my code:

```
    create_url = "https://myjira/rest/api/2/issue/"

    jira_hash = 
    {
    "fields": {
    "project": {
    "id": "51606"
    },
    "issuetype": {
    "name": "SOAK EVENT"
    },
    "priority": {
    "name": "Critical"
    },
    "labels": ["Chandler"],
    "customfield_10012": {
    "id": "10006"
    },
    "fixVersions": [{
    "name": "2019-05-r1"
    }],
    "summary": "10297",
    "description": "description"
    }
    }

    HTTParty.post(create_url,
    :body => jira_hash.to_json,
    :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json', 'Authorization' 
     => auth})
```

Comment: try replacing `to_json` to `as_json` and let me know.

Comment: I found the reason is encrypted 'username:password' fail to be parsed in the request. I try to code it like this way and it works.


`auth = {:username => 'test', :password => 'test'}
 HTTParty.post(create_url,
    :body => jira_hash.to_json,
    :headers => {'Content-Type' => 'application/json'},
    :basic_auth => auth)`